# Can computers built in minecraft be used to hijack hosts?

Tags: virtualization

As people build more powerful computers in minecraft which can then run programs, is there a way to use those computers to run programs that hijack the host in some way?

Possible contest example would be to use a computer built in minecraft to create a network connection from that computer to a specified target.

There's a lot between inside the game and the target, but in principle is a computer inside a gameworld not much different than a virtual machine and its relationship to its host?

Will this become exploitable and worth considering?

Comment: It's a ***lot*** different from a VM and its host...

Comment: @schroeder it's code running on a processor. Not really different at all, except that it's in fact even less secure than how virtual machines operate.

Comment: @IDNeon In principle, you can build a Turing complete computer [using rocks](https://xkcd.com/505/). Can I use a rock computer to hijack earth? No. Minecraft computers are closer to rock computers than virtual machines. Those computers are basically a simulated CPU that implements logic gates using minecraft objects. It cannot perform any sort of syscalls or run any code directly on the host's CPU. As such it does not expose any more attack surface than normal gameplay, so schroeder's answer is correct.

Answer (score 5):

That just sounds like a Minecraft exploit with extra steps...

If that ever becomes possible, then the issue is not the "computer" that was built inside, but the vulnerability in Minecraft to allow it. And at that point, you just trigger the vulnerability. No need to go through the work to build a computer...

Comment: I disagree on the basis that minecraft can't be edited to inject code onto the platform it's running on.

However a computer can be built into minecraft that must run its code on the hardware it is running on.

Comment: The 'computer' in Minecraft must run on Minecraft. Minecraft runs on the OS. The OS runs on hardware. Each layer can only do what the layer below exposes functionality for.

Answer (score 0):

#### That depends entirely on the mods being used

A computer purely built from redstone cannot communicate with the network, as there is no interface that allows it to do so.

However, there are mods, which allow more sophisticated computers to be built, such as [ComputerCraft](https://www.computercraft.info/). They include interpreters like Lua, which allow players to write quite complex programs, such as a control system for a nuclear reactor. Depending on how the mod is implented, it is *possible* that the interpreter can connect to a network and send packets, or access the host's filesystem. In fact, programs "saved" onto the virtual computer are stored directly onto the server's disk. So in a way, you already *have* limited access to the host's filesystem.

So yes, with mods, it's absolutely possible that this *could* happen.